# Replace file content without creating a new file with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm playing with Node.js `fs.writeFile()` flags to find the right file for my problem: I want to replace the content of a file but throw an error if the file does not exist.

My first try was with `r+` but I have issues if the new content is shorter than the old one:

```
fs.writeFileSync('test', '11111111111');
> 111111111111
fs.writeFileSync('test', '22', {flag: 'r+'})
> 221111111111
```

Removing the flag solve the problem (give `22`) but create a new file if `test` doesn't exist.

Is it doable with a flag or do I need to detect file existence before (not very found of that)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in a single step: opening a file for writing will create the file if it does not exist, while opening the file with `r+` mode presents the problem you mention.

I see two options:

1. Test for existence using `fs.stat()`, then `fs.writeFile()` in `w` mode.
2. Open the file in `r+` mode, write to it, then `fs.ftruncate()` the file to the desired size.

I recommend the first approach. The code will be easier to read and reason about.

Comment: I was always told testing the file before is an anti-pattern because it won't guarantee the file status when you'll write. I may have concurrent access on this file so isn't the 2nd better? Thank you

Comment: Since I want to override the file, I found out the best method is indeed delete it, watch for error (if it doesn't exist), then write it with default flag. Thank you